# Run or keep a custom function alive even after the app is fully closed [Closed even from the recent tabs] - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile, task

Suppose, I have a function which continuously checks if a item is available or not and I am trying to find a way which would keep the function alive even after the app is fully closed using java - android studio!

Thanks in advanced!!!